# TC symbol on battery schematic

Tags: batteries

This is a schematic diagram of the connector on a BA-5590 battery.

What is the "TCn" symbol?[image]

[Battery Datasheet](https://www.tacticaleng.com/mc_files/1/BA-5590:U00.pdf)

Comment: Please add a link to datasheet into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thermal Cutout, a safety device to prevent catastrophic damage in the event of overheating due to overload.

Comment: Yes the battery can fail from internal short circuits  resulting in circulating currents that do not pass thru the fuses but aggravated by load current so the fuse path is opened by either TC. Either the battery pack must be thermally coupled to TC or each cell must have one

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from the [BA 5590 datasheet](https://www.batteriesandbutter.com/datasheets/BA5590.pdf).*

It's a non-replaceable fuse. TC probably stands for "thermal cutout" in which case it will blow on both over-current and over temperature in the event of the case internals going faulty - due to wiring or internal battery fault.